# Problem adding class to body_class

Tags: php, filters, css

I am trying to add additional classes to `<body>` based on certain conditions, so I have this code in my `functions.php` file of the theme :

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_body_class' );
function custom_body_class( $classes ) {

if ( !is_home() && !is_archive() ) {
    $classes[] = array_push( $classes, 'new-class' );
}

if ( condition ) {
    $classes[] = array_push( $classes, 'conditional-class' );
}

return $classes;
}
```

The code above works but when I look at the body class in the HTML output, it will show an additional number as the class depending on its location in the array, for example :

```
<body class="single logged-in new-class 4 conditional-class 6">
```

Or :

```
<body class="single logged-in admin-bar new-class 5 conditional-class 7">
```

I think this is probably more of a problem with my PHP code but I can't see what's causing it. Any ideas how I can add the conditional body classes without this problem? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `array_push()` incorrectly.

Do this:

```
$classes[] = 'new-class';
```

Or this:

```
array_push( $classes, 'new-class' );
```

But not:

```
$classes[] = array_push( $classes, 'new-class' );
```